# what android system will do to alternative image resource

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, animation

I noticed that android did some extra work for the alternative resources, if the matching resource was not found.

For example:

I put some images (size:640x960) into the `drawable-hdpi` folder, and none in the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.

Using `decodeResource()` to load the image:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(imageView.getResources(),
                             imageRes,mBitmapFactoryOptions);
```

- On a xxhdpi screen phone (nexus 5), the method takes extra 30-50 milliseconds to execute; other than a hdpi screen phone (samsung I9100).
- It's not big deal while load only one image, but it made a lot of difference while I am creating frame by frame animation.
- I have checked [screens_support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but have no clue what android system did and how to avoid it.

Thanks for any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's no resource for your device, but there is one for other screens, that can be adapted to yours, Android adapts it. When it comes to drawables, Android rescales images by yourDPI/imageDPI ratio. This is the reason, why loading drawables can be slower. You can verify that using profiler and watching closely loading tasks.

To avoid it, you have to provide images for all screen configurations you're planning to use or use assets folder to manually load images.

Comment: Also take in account that different hardware performs differently... my 2 cents.

Comment: thanks for the help. @Bob, could you be more specific about "different hardware performs differently"? it makes me feeling unsafe...

Comment: Every device has a different CPU (which is the heart - ok it's actually the brain - of any computer). Some don't even have GPUs (the Graphical CPUs). And different clock speeds. Never to mention the users who root their devices and are able to over/under clock their devices. So every device performs better or worse when compared to another one. If you **optimize your code to run decently on a low performing hardware**, it will be more than brilliant on a power device.